# Scroll to next div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m working on this [page](http://www.transportlab.com/)

As you can see, in the bottom-middle there is an `arrow` that right now I haven´t been able to make it scroll to the next section.

You can see the next project by normal scroll but I want to activate it also on the `arrow`.

This is the markup:

```
<a id="arrow-down" href="#" onclick="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
    $('#arrow-down').on('click', function () {
        var ele = $(this).closest("div").find(".project.skrollable");
        // this will search within the section
        $("html, body").animate({
             scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top
        }, 100);
        return false;
    });
```

Any ideas what I´m doing wrong? or how can I achieve it?

Comment: You could just use anchorpoints to achieve the scrolling to a specific place

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="btn" href="#" ></a>
```

Give the `div` `Id` to `<a>` `href`

```
$window = $(window);
        $window.scroll(function () {
            if ($window.scrollTop() >= 0 && $window.scrollTop() < 1000) {
                $("#btn").attr("href", "#div1");
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() >= 1000 && $window.scrollTop() < 2000) {
                $("#btn").attr("href", "#div2");
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() >= 2000 && $window.scrollTop() < 3000) {
                $("#btn").attr("href", "#div3");
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() >= 3000 && $window.scrollTop() < 4000) {
                $("#btn").attr("href", "#div4");
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() >= 4000) {
                $("#btn").attr("href", "#div5");
            }
        });


        $("#btn").click(function () {

            var div = $("#btn")[0].hash;
            var lastChar = div[div.length - 1];
            lastChar++;
            $("#btn").attr("href", "#div" + lastChar + "");
        });
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b4y71wd8/4/)

Comment: and If I'm at `div#2`and what to scroll to `div#3`? I don't think this will work...

Comment: suppose i clicked button two times(so I'll be on second div now) and i scroll up to top manually using scroll bar.

if i clicked button again it'll show me the third div. :(

Comment: Now check my post :) :)

Answer (score 0):

i found you that, you added required JS at wrong place. (currently it's on line: 562 according to source view)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archcase.com/wp-content/themes/archcase/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script><!-- the mousewheel plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archcase.com/wp-content/themes/archcase/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script><!-- the jScrollPane script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archcase.com/wp-content/themes/archcase/custom_templates_css/Mullion/js/skrollr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archcase.com/wp-content/themes/archcase/custom_templates_css/Mullion/js/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archcase.com/wp-content/themes/archcase/custom_templates_css/Mullion/js/main.js"></script>
```

add these js includes to the top of page. it should be on line:60 at least.